# Check to return true if any list element found in string

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I want the simplest (preferably `lambda`) function, which returns `True` if any element list is present in a string.

Background

```py
df['cybertruck'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(lambda x: 'cybertruck' in x.lower())
```

The above lambda function works fine, but I'd like to be able to pass a list of values in, such as `['cyber truck', 'cybertruck']` in and if any (either) of those terms were found in the string, the value assigned to the column `'cybertruck'` would be `True` (else `False`).

What's an an easy way to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to test for every word in a list and return a boolean. Then, call the [`any` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) on the resulting list, which returns `True` if at least one element of the list is `True`:

```py
lambda lst, x: any([s in x.lower() for s in lst])
```

In fact, you can get better performance by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension by simply removing the brackets. This way, `any` will stop iterating and return immediately as soon as it finds the first `True` value, saving some computational power:

```py
lambda lst, x: any(s in x.lower() for s in lst)
```

Example:

```py
>>> f = lambda lst, x: any(s in x.lower() for s in lst)
>>> f(['cyber truck', 'cybertruck'], tweet)
True
```

In your case, if the lambda function needs to receive only one argument from the dataframe, instead of passing the list of possible strings, you can either hard-code it:

```py
df['cybertruck'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(lambda x: any(s in x.lower() for s in ['cyber truck', 'cybertruck']))
```

or store it in a different variable:

```py
strings = ['cyber truck', 'cybertruck']
df['cybertruck'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(lambda x: any(s in x.lower() for s in strings))
```

Comment: Your third code block example worked like a charm. I've seen `any()` come up before but never sure how to use it until now!

Comment: I think the list comprehension is unnecessary eagerness.  You could probably use a generator expression like: f = lambda lst, x: any(s in x.lower() for s in lst) .  It should be a little faster and definitely require less memory.

Comment: @dstromberg That's true. Nice catch! I'll update my answer accordingly.